# C++ - macro for calling function based on enum type

Tags: c++, c, macros

I have an `enum` and a function which takes this enum and uses a `switch case` to call the right function:

```
enum { FOO, BAR, ... }   // 10-15 operations

void do_action() {
  switch(enum) {
    case FOO: fn_FOO(); break;
    case BAR: fn_BAR(); break;   
    case default: fn_DEFAULT(); break;
  }
}
```

I have been trying to find a way to use Macros to automatically generate the above case statements (to avoid boiler plate) but I'm new to C++ and google hasn't been of much help.

I'm aware of an alternative way of avoiding some of the boilerplate case statements by using an array of function pointers, but I'm really interested to find out how this can be done using  Macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat the enum values only once, you may do

```
#define FOOBAR do_FOOBAR(FOO) do_FOOBAR(BAR) // 10-15 operations
```

Then declare your enum:

```
#define do_FOOBAR(x) x,
enum E { FOOBAR };
#undef do_FOOBAR
```

And for the switch:

```
switch(e) {
#define do_FOOBAR(x) case x: fn_##x(); break;
FOOBAR
#undef do_FOOBAR
default:
    fn_DEFAULT();
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be fairly simple with macros and token pasting, e.g.

```
#define do_action(e) fn_##e()

do_action(FOO); // -> fn_FOO();
do_action(BAR); // -> fn_BAR();
```

however this really is a 1980s C solution to a 2014 C++ problem, and you should almost certainly reconsider.

Comment: +1 for last sentence! You could always just wrap your enum into an integral constant and overload by type: `fn(std::integral_constant<int, FOO>{} )`

Comment: In principle, I agree that macros are not always the best approach. Is there a way to even remove the repetitive `do_action` statements? Like automatically enumerating the types of an enum?

Answer (score 1):

The `##` operator can be used to join preprocessor tokens together to make single tokens, so you can use that to bodge the enumerator names onto a common prefix for function names:

```
#define CASE(X) case X: fn_##X(); break;

switch(e){   // "enum" not a valid identifier
    CASE(FOO)
    CASE(BAR)
    default: fn_DEFAULT(); break;  // needs to be treated differently
}
```

While such monstrosities are occasionally useful, always try to do what you want within the language before reaching for the preprocessor. As you say, function pointers, or virtual functions, or some other language mechanism can probably be used here.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid repeating even the `CASE(enum_value)` for each possible value of the enum?

Comment: @jeffreyveon: Not with the standard preprocessor. You might be able to find, or write, a code generator to produce this from the enum definition, but I don't know anything about such tools.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to go other direction than what macros are pointing except in some situations like conditional compilation etc.

I would have used a map which would hold enum as key and function pointers as its value_type.